# help to find working alternative

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

Im using

```
$A.get("event.force:navigateToSObject")
$A.get("e.force:editRecord")
```

and im getting back null from them. I read that they work in pages but im trying to get it to work from a .app is there an alternative I can use so the edit and view functions will work from the app instead of coming back viewRec is undefined and $A.get(...) is undefined

Answer (score 0):

These events only exist in certain contexts, because they are handled by the Lightning Experience runtime. If you're getting null values, that means you can't use that event in that context. As an alternative, you can simply set `window.location` to the record Id, such as `/001300000012345`.

Comment: thanks im new to programming and was wondering if there was a site with practice problems and solutions to get more familiar with the programming side of salesforce

Comment: @Guest The [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/) has you covered. They have all kinds of topics, including Basic, Intermediate, and Advanced programming topics in Salesforce.